# Apply a class to the First element (A) of Each element (LI)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I in jQuery find the first `a` tag within each `$(".tweet li")` and make it have the class '`toptweet`' ???

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.tweet li').each(function(){
    $(this).find('a').first().addClass('toptweet');
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just change one element, not the first <a> under each li.tweet

Comment: @Kyle - I like your answer and comment, almost the same as mine :P

Comment: Everyone, the `first()` function will [Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set](http://api.jquery.com/first/) so this answer won't do what was asked for in the question.

Comment: Okay ignore all the above comments now that this one has been fixed so it works :)

Comment: @appclay + Kyle  you are both correct, my original code wouldn't have worked. I upvoted both of your answers.

Comment: @MarkBrown I removed your downvote. I just want to be sure a correct answer gets to the top. Thanks for correcting yours.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".tweet li").each(function(){
  $(this).find("a:eq(0)").addClass("toptweet");
});
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the `:eq(0)` filter is faster than the `:first` filter I put in my answer, so this is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.tweet li').each(function() { 
    $(this).find('a:first').addClass('toptweet');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li.tweet").("a:eq(1)").addclass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tweet li a:first").addClass('toptweet');
```